Given $D, X_1, X_2, Z$, how is $E(D Z)$ related with the nonparametric partial correlation $\eta^2_{D\sim Z\mid X_1, X_2}$?
Let $D, X_1, X_2, Z$ be some arbitrary random variables. If it is easier to think, we can assume they are mean zero.
I'm curious if there is any relationship between the correlation $E(D Z)$ and the nonparametric partial correlation $\eta^2_{D\sim Z\mid X_1, X_2}$ between random variables $D$ and $Z$? For example, if I know $E(D Z)$, how can I use it to write $\eta^2_{D\sim Z\mid X_1, X_2}$? or vice versa. It is also clear to me that extra quantities must be identified in order to fully bridge those two types of correlations.
Let me explain the notation $\eta^2_{D\sim Z\mid X_1, X_2}$ of the nonparametric partial correlation between the variables $D$ and $Z$ given $X_1, X_2$ a little bit more here.
\begin{align*}
\eta^2_{D\sim Z\mid X_1, X_2} &= Corr^2\big(\{D - E(D\mid X_1, X_2)\} ,E\left[\{D- E(D\mid X_1, X_2)\}\mid X_1, X_2, Z\right]\big)
\end{align*}
Since I didn't assume $E[D\mid X_1, X_2, Z]$ to be a linear regression function, notice $\eta^2_{D\sim Z\mid X_1, X_2}$ is not the partial correlation between the variables $D$ and $Z$ given controlling variables $X_1, X_2$.

Isn't $E(X_1 \mid X_1, X_2)$ just $X_1$ itself?

I'm very sorry I mistyped. It is $E[D \mid X_1, X_2]$.

With the fixed typos, now there is no need for subscripts in $X_1$ and $X_2$ since they always show up together. They can just be called $X$.

For the $\mathbb{C}\mathrm{or}$ in the $\eta$ definition, you mean the marginal one, rather than conditional on $X$. Am I correct?

Do you mind provide some context where this definition arose from?

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ always show up together in the OP, I will just use $X$ to denote them. Also, the terms "correlation" and "covariance" are used casually in the OP. I'll specifically study "covariance" here.

The covariance part in $\eta^2$ is
$$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}} \newcommand{\V}{\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}} \newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \begin{align}
&\phantom{{}={}} \C\left\lbrace D-\E(D\mid X),\quad \E\left[D-\E(D\mid X) \mid X,Z \right] \right\rbrace
\\
&=\C\left\lbrace D-\E(D\mid X), \quad \E(D\mid X,Z)-\E(D\mid X) \right\rbrace \\
&=\C\left\lbrace D-\E(D\mid X), \quad \E(D\mid X,Z)\right\rbrace - \\ 
&\qquad\qquad \underset{0}{\underbrace{ \C\left\lbrace D-\E(D\mid X), \quad \E(D\mid X,)\right\rbrace  }} \\
&=\E\left \lbrace 
  \C\left[D-\E(D\mid X),\quad \E(D\mid X,Z)\mid X\right] \right\rbrace + \\
&\qquad\qquad
  \C\left( \underset{0}{\underbrace{ \E\left[D-\E(D\mid X) \mid X\right] }},\quad \E\left[\E(D\mid X,Z)\mid X\right] \right)
 \\
&=\E\left\lbrace \C\left[D,\quad  \E(D\mid X,Z)\mid X\right] - \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad  \underset{0}{\underbrace{ \C\left[\E(D\mid X), \quad\E(D\mid X,Z)\mid X\right] }} \rbrace\\
&=\E\left\lbrace \C\left[D,\quad \E(D\mid X,Z)\mid X\right] \right\rbrace \tag{1}\label{1} \\ 
&=\E\left\lbrace \underset{0}{\underbrace{\C\left[D-\E(D\mid X,Z),\quad \E(D\mid X,Z)\mid X\right]}}  + \V\left[ \E(D\mid X,Z) \mid X \right]
\right\rbrace \\
&=\E\left\lbrace  \V\left[ \E(D\mid X,Z) \mid X \right]
\right\rbrace \\
&\geq 0.
\end{align}$$
So, even without squaring, this covariance is already non-negative. Compare \eqref{1} with the (not necessarily non-negative)
$$
\C(D,\ Z)=\E\left\lbrace \C(D,\quad Z\mid X)\right\rbrace + \C\left[\E(D\mid X), \quad\E(Z\mid X)\right].
$$
Apart from the extra second term in $\C(D,\ Z)$, it seems more interesting to me to compare the square of terms inside their first braces:
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ccc}
  \C^2 [\,D, & \E(D\mid X,Z) & {}\mid X\,] \\
  \C^2 [\,D, & Z & {}\mid X\,]\\
\end{array}\right.$$
I intuitively think that the upper line will have a larger value, because $\E(D\mid X,Z)$ (as a function of $Z$) is made specifically to approximate $D$, compared with $Z$ itself.
We can also rewrite $\C(D,\ Z \mid X)$ as
$$\begin{align}
\C(D,\ Z \mid X)
&=\E\left[\underset{0}{\underbrace{\C(D,\ Z\mid X,Z)}} \mid X\right]+\C\left[\E(D|X,Z),\ \E(Z\mid X,Z) \mid X\right] \\
&=\C\left[Z,\ \E(D|X,Z)  \mid X\right]. 
\end{align}$$
This provides another comparison with \eqref{1}:
$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ccc}
  \C [\,D, & \E(D\mid X,Z) & {}\mid X\,] \\
  \C [\,Z, & \E(D\mid X,Z) & {}\mid X\,]\\
\end{array}\right.$$

The discussion is very helpful, thank you
